# How to pulsing sprite until touch on the screen in cocos2d-x for android?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I have used CCSequence, But i am not able to use CCRepeatForEver.

CCFiniteTimeAction *s = CCSequence::actions(
         CCScaleBy::actionWithDuration(1, 1.0),`enter code here`
         CCScaleBy::actionWithDuration(1, -1.0),
         CCScaleBy::actionWithDuration(1, 1.0),
                 CCScaleBy::actionWithDuration(1, -1.0),
                 CCScaleBy::actionWithDuration(1, 1.0),
                         CCScaleBy::actionWithDuration(1, -1.0),NULL);
         circle->runAction(s);

I want to use CCRepeatForEver in cocos2d-x for android.
please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, why haven't you used it? It is nowhere in your code. Also what esxactly does "I am not able to use CCRepeatForever" mean? Do you get compilation errors or runtime?

Looking at your code, the problem is that you assign a CCSequence to a CCFiniteTimeAction type, and CCRepeatForever expects a CCActionInterval type. This is how the inheritance goes :

```
CCSequence -> CCActionInterval -> CCFiniteTimeAction -> …
```

So it is perfectly valid to do what you did, but won't work with CCRepeatForever, as it wouldn't know what to do with the type you provided. So to make it work you need to change in two places in your code :

```
CCActionInterval *s = CCSequence::create(…);
//or
CCSequence *s = CCSequence::create(…);
//and at the end
circle->runAction(CCRepeatForever::create(s));
```

Also if you'd notice, I've changed `CCSequence::actions` to `CCSequence::create`, as this is the way it should be.